# How to load a SharedObject from another Swf file in actionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, save, load

This code works, but when I put the loadBtn and the function 'loadNames' in another swf file, the program traces this: "saved names: undefined", in addition I'd like to specify the path of the object saved:how can i do that?

```
var SO:SharedObject=SharedObject.getLocal("mySave");

var archive:Array=new Array();
var counter:Number=-1;

saveBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveName);
loadBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadNames);

function saveName(event:Event) {
    counter++;

    archive[counter]=input.text;

    SO.data.arrSaved=archive;

    SO.flush();
}

function loadNames(event:Event) {

    trace("saved names: "+SO.data.arrSaved);

}
```

Comment: Read carefully about second argument: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#getLocal()

Comment: It works,  I had to add the slash, however i can't see any type of file inside the folder where the swf files are stored, the shared object should be there, doesn't it? can you explain me that? Thanks

Comment: No the shared object is not there. It is stored in (usually) a hidden folder on your hard drive. Just google "where are flash shared objects stored on my Windows PC?" Or something like that.

Comment: @GianLuke94 Neal Davis is absolutely right. **SharedObject** is intended to be a cookie-type persistent data storage for SWF applications running on web-sites, which SFWs has no (totally should have no) actual place on the local storage.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll keep it in mind